# Attachments with php's built-in SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, attachment

Is there a way I can add a soap attachment to a request using PHP's built-in SoapClient classes? It doesn't look like it's supported, but maybe I can manually build the mime boundaries? I know the PEAR SOAP library supports them, but in order to use that I have to rewrite my entire library to use it.

Comment: I blogged about the full solution [SoapClient with Attachments](http://quickshiftin.com/blog/2013/09/soap-client-attachments-php/)

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just send  files using [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) rather than implement [SoapAttachment](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments) ? Here is an example :

**Client**

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
        'location' => "http://localhost/lab/stackoverflow/a.php?h=none",
        'uri' => "http://localhost/",
        'trace' => 1
));

// Method 1 Array
// File to upload
$file = "golf3.png";

// First Example
$data = array();
$data['name'] = $file;
$data['data'] = getDataURI($file, "image/png");
echo "Example 1: ";
echo ($return = $client->upload($data)) ? "File Uploaded : $return bytes" : "Error Uploading Files";

// Method 2 Objects
// File to upload
$file = "original.png";

// Second Example
$attachment = new ImageObj($file);
$param = new SoapVar($attachment, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "ImageObj");
$param = new SoapParam($param, "param");
echo "Example 2: ";
echo ($return = $client->uploadObj($attachment)) ? "File Uploaded : $return bytes" : "Error Uploading Files";
```

**Output**

```
Example 1: File Uploaded : 976182 bytes
Example 2: File Uploaded : 233821 bytes
```

**Server**

```
class UploadService {

    public function upload($args) {
        $file = __DIR__ . "/test/" . $args['name'];
        return file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($args['data']));
    }

    public function uploadObj($args) {
        $file = __DIR__ . "/test/" . $args->name;
        $data = sprintf("data://%s;%s,%s", $args->mime, $args->encoding, $args->data);
        return file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($data));
    }
}

try {
    $server = new SOAPServer(NULL, array(
            'uri' => 'http://localhost/'
    ));
    $server->setClass('UploadService');
    $server->handle();

} catch (SOAPFault $f) {
    print $f->faultstring;
}
```

**Client Util**

```
// Function Used
function getDataURI($image, $mime = '') {
    return 'data: ' . (function_exists('mime_content_type') ? 
            mime_content_type($image) : $mime) . ';base64,' . 
            base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
}


// Simple Image Object
class ImageObj{
    function __construct($file, $mime = "") {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->name = basename($file);
        if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
            $this->mime = mime_content_type($file);
        } elseif (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
            $this->mime = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $file);
        } else {
            $this->mime = $mime;
        }

        $this->encoding = "base64";
        $this->data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty sweet, and thanks for the example, but if I gather correctly, you're just using a [simple type String](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14154_01/dev.835/e12868/e01_soap_types.htm#sthref261) to send the image.  And since you have the server as well, you know how to parse out and decode the image.  I don't think it will work in cases where I'm only writing the client and the service expects an attachment, or am I wrong about that?

Comment: @quickshiftin i think you should test it first ..... I used [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and i testing it it works fine

Comment: Interesting, looks like that's where that `'data: ' . (function_exists('mime_content_type') ? 
            mime_content_type($image) : $mime) . ';base64,'` bit came from, I was wondering about that.  I'll take a deeper look at it.

Comment: Still experimenting, but it looks like the service I'm trying to hit to test it on is expecting [SwA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_with_Attachments).  Doesn't seem to be excepting requests with the paradigm you've shown.

Comment: While this isn't what I was looking for, it did drive me to do a lot of research and get a start implementing what I wanted.  The bounty is yours!

Comment: Just saw your messages .... Are you implementing Server & Client or you are implementing a Soap Client that connects to a server ? And thanks for the bounty

Comment: Implementing a client that talks to a foreign server right now.  But once the attachment code is working, it could be used from SoapServer too.  I already have the download side working, using [php-mime-mail-parser](https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/).  The upload piece has proven a bit harder (I think I have it, but the remote server doesn't LOL).  I'm taking the approach I outlined in my answer for the implementation.  NP on the bounty, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can i see the wsdl .. you can put it on pastebin .. let me see what you are dealing with ... i may be able to help

Comment: https://um.voipconsultants.biz:8443/wsdl.fcgi?get=Voicemail.xsd  *get_vm_greeting*, I've implemented, *set_vm_greeting* is what I'm working on.

Comment: That is one crappy web service .... i see why you are having issues .... `SetVMGreetingRequest` is a complex type which was not defined .. tell then to give you a sample wsdl request they are expecting ... i can have you figure how to compose the message

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can build the MIME component of the message using something like [imap_mail_compose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-compose.php).

You'll need to construct a multipart message as they do in the first example, putting the XML from the `$request` parameter, from an overridden `SoapClient::__doRequest` method, into the first part of the MIME message.

Then you can do as others have shown in the first `imap_mail_compose` example to add one or more messages parts with attachments.  These attachements can, but do not have to be base64 encoded, they can just as well be binary.  The encoding for each part is specified by part-specific headers.

You'll also need to cook up an appropriate set of HTTP headers, per the [SwA Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments) @Baba linked to earlier.

Once it's all said and done, you should have something looking like the examples from that document:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: Multipart/Related; boundary=MIME_boundary; type=text/xml;
        start="<claim061400a.xml@claiming-it.com>"
Content-Description: This is the optional message description.

--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <claim061400a.xml@claiming-it.com>

<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
..
<theSignedForm href="cid:claim061400a.tiff@claiming-it.com"/>
..
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: image/tiff
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <claim061400a.tiff@claiming-it.com>

...binary TIFF image...
--MIME_boundary--
```

And you can send that across the wire with the aforementioned overridden `SoapClient::__doRequest` method.  Things I have noticed in trying to implement it myself thus far:

- You may need to create an *href* URI reference from each SOAP node to the corresponding attachment, something like `href="cid:claim061400a.tiff@claiming-it.com"` above
- You will need to extract the *boundary* component from the MIME content returned by `imap_mail_compose` for use in an HTTP *Content-Type* header
- Don't forget the *start* component of the *Content-Type* header either, it should look something like this:
- `imap_mail_compose` appears fairly minimal (but low hanging fruit), if it proves insufficient, consider [Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected) instead

> Content-Type: Multipart/Related; boundary=MIME_boundary;
>   type=text/xml; start=""

Lastly, I'm not sure how evenly the various implementations of *SwA* are out there on the Internet...  Suffice it to say, I've not been able to get an upload to a remote service with a crude implementation of what I've described above yet.  It does seem like *SwA* is the typical SOAP attachment paradigm of choice though, from what I gather reading around on the net.